# can I trigger click event onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having anchor tag in my page. I like to trigger click event onload . Which means I wanna open this page "http://XXXXX.com" with new tab. Because I don't wanna popup blockers. Is there anyway to do this?

anchor attrs are given bellow

```
id="add_redirect"
href="http://XXXXX.com"
target="_blank"
```

Comment: Please don't try to bypass popup blockers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to bypass pop-up blockers on page load, triggering the `click` event synthetically probably won't work. Browsers are smart enough to know when a `click` is user-generated vs. when you've called the `click` function on the DOM element (on those browsers were that even works). Examples: http://jsbin.com/avibi3/3, http://jsbin.com/avibi3/4

Using jQuery's `trigger` mechanism certainly won't do it, because it doesn't really trigger a `click` event at all; it just fires the handlers that jQuery hooked up *(edit: and, apparently, ones defined via an `onclick` attribute — see Sukhi's answer — but not ones attached via `addEventListener`)*. If that's what you want to do, Sukhi's answer shows you how, although I always say: If you want code to be run from two different places, put it in a function, and call that function from two different places (rather than putting it in a `click` handler and then simulating a click just to run the code). There are valid use cases for `trigger` (mostly relating to integrating with third-party scripts), but for running your *own* code from two different places, it's a symptom of a design problem.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, you can use a click event called `onLoad()`. Just use the `setTimeout()` method in jquery. It will call a click function without clicking it. Here is an example:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#add_redirect").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

This will work for you when the page start to load and the time delay is 10ms which is negligible.
Syntax has been corrected.

Comment: Only using setTimeout seems to trigger the click action, so this is the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following code in the page load

```
document.getElementById('add_redirect').click();
```

Comment: Sorry.. This is all Javascript

Answer (score 3):

Using JQuery you can do that pretty easy. The earlier posted solution also work of course.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#add_redirect").trigger('click');
});
```

**[TRY DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ediwe3)**

Comment: Note that that will only trigger the `click` handler **if** the handler was hooked up with jQuery. Which is fine, if you're using jQuery, you want to use it to hook up event handlers, but for instance an `onclick=...` in the markup won't get tiggered. It's just worth calling out.

Comment: Interesting, my mistake for generalizing. What it won't do is fire handlers attached via DOM2 methods (`addEventListener`): http://jsbin.com/avibi3 I made the mistake of assuming from that that it also wouldn't fire an `onclick="..."` from the markup, but apparently it does. In any case, the DOM2 thing is an important caveat. And Chrome's popup-blocker isn't fooled in any case: http://jsbin.com/avibi3/3, http://jsbin.com/avibi3/4