# Redirect to a page using JavaScript after AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an interesting issue:

Currently I have a button that says "Print", which is located at the end of a series of pages where users can enter information, make selections and obtain a unique result.

When they press this button, data representing the state of the application will be sent via JQuery's [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Once the target script processes that data and stores it in the database against a unique ID, that ID is sent back to the success handler. The ID is then used in the success handler to open a new window that will pull down the data they sent off and display it in a printable manner.

```
$.post("api/PrintJob.php", applicationStateJSON, function(response)
{
    window.open("print/?job=" + response.token);

}, "json");
```

Because the `window.open()` call is not directly within a click handler, *the popup is understandably blocked*.

I can't simply use `window.location.href = ?;` because the state of the application needs to be maintained in case the user wants to go back a step and make some changes, etc.

Currently my only solution is to have a secondary button appear within the success handler, and have that launch the print window. I would however prefer to retain the current feel and have the window open in a new tab / window / popup / whatever if possible, without being blocked.

Maybe there is a way that I can launch the popup empty when I initially click print, and then reload it when the data has hit the database?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Yes you can open a print popup by user interaction, then access it through the main the window, by using window.postMessage for communication. Or you could trick the browser, by creating a ghost anchor tag. You could put a URL with get parameters, a _blank target and trigger it with a javascript generated click event. Or, maybe the best way is a DOM popup over your app, and the document to be printed in a iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion will be to open a window on first click and then do a post from the newly opened window. The response of the post is received in the newly opened window. This response can be used to paint the new window using JS/JQuery.

Comment: Ended up sending the data straight to the window via GET, then in that window inserting the data and doing a `window.location.href = '?job=blah'` which I actually think works a lot better than how I had it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the scenario, an option could be to have second button hidden and trigger the click once the token comes back.

```
var token;

$('#hiddenbutton').click(function(){
     window.open("print/?job=" + token);
 }):

$.post("api/PrintJob.php", applicationStateJSON, function(response)
{
    token = response.token;
    $('#hiddenbutton').trigger('click');
}, "json");
```

Comment: Surely something this sneaky is countered by the browser already, but I'll give it a shot..

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966832/can-i-trigger-click-event-onload

Comment: @MartyWallace that's pretty funny. Yeah, my answer was based on the question and trying to trigger click outside of post callback. I like your resolution.